# Derive a class name from another class name in template

Tags: c++, templates, arguments, class-names

In order to use a library, I need to use different classes that have the same base name. I.e.

```
MyClass
MyClassImpl
PreMyClass
```

And so on. in order to use them with template I need pass all these class names.

```
template <typename T, typename TImpl, typename PreT>
class ClassThatUsesAllTheseObjects
{
  public:
  ClassThatUsesAllTheseObjects();
  private:
  T myClass;
  TImpl myClassImpl;
  PreT myPreClass;
};
```

It's possibile to obtain the same result giving only the principal `MyClass` as template argument, building other names when needed?

Comment: Preprocessor is used for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am not sure of the settings in your question, but in some cases, you might want to do something like the [trait mechanism](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/442).

Suppose you write a concrete `MyClass`, and others like it. For each group of concrete classes, you do something like:

```
// This is common
template <typename T>
struct foo_traits
{

};

// This is for each set of concrete classes
template<>
struct foo_traits<MyClass>
{
   using Impl = MyClassImpl;
   using Pre = PreMyClass; 
};

...
```

Then you use the traits class like this:

```
template <
    typename T, 
    class Impl = typename foo_traits<T>::Impl,
    class Pre = typename foo_traits<T>::Pre>
class ClassThatUsesAllTheseObjects
{
  public:
  ClassThatUsesAllTheseObjects();
  private:
  T myClass;
  Impl myClassImpl;
  Pre myPreClass;
};
```

This allows you to explain what are the "natural friends" of your principal concrete classes.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two options:

1. Use a tag to make the difference. So you would have e.g. a `template <class T> myClass`, a `struct impl_t{}, struct pre_t{}, struct base_t{}` and then use gthem in this way:

code:

```
myClass<base_t> ; // instead of plain MyClass
myClass<impl_t> ;// instead of plain MyClassImpl
myClass<pre_t> ; // instead of myPreClass
```

Template specialization should make their definition easy/possible.

2. traits, but there is already an answer on that side :-)

Comment: Tags are a nice solution, but I prefer traits because I cannot modify these classes. But it's a nice idea too.